# Speed up node pool delete on GKE

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine

It takes two minutes to delete GKE node pools. Are there any ways of speeding that up?

Currently I just (using the container Go SDK):

```golang
import (
    container "cloud.google.com/go/container/apiv1"
)

containerClient, _ := container.NewClusterManagerClient(context.Background())

op, _ := containerClient.DeleteNodePool(context.Background(), &containerpb.DeleteNodePoolRequest{
    Name: "projects/my-project/locations/my-zone/clusters/my-cluster/nodePools/my-pool",
})
```

and wait for `op` to finish.

Comment: I need to check, but I believe when you delete a node pool the nodes are being drained, thus they terminate gracefully and take the time required to gracefully evict all the pods on the nodes

Comment: @PatrickW according to [gcloud cli docs](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/container/node-pools/delete): *This command does not gracefully drain the nodes prior to deleting them*, so if go sdk works the same way it wouldn't be the explanation.

Comment: Does deleting node pool using cloud console work faster?

Comment: Thanks PatrickW and @HelloWorld, it takes around two minutes to delete node pools, same time from gcloud and Go. I was hoping there was some hack to speed it up, but maybe that's just the fastest it gets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not aware of any faster ways to do that. You could skip waiting for the deletion to complete and do something else in the meanwhile, but that wouldn't make the deletion itself any faster.
When deleting many pools they can issue deletion requests for all the pools and then wait for them all to finish.